# How can I keep one table row always at the bottom of my table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm building a MUI table which displays rows and the last row is the total number of colors. The issue that I'm struggling right  now is that when I don't have any results in the table, the last row moves up but I have to keep it at the bottom always.
I've tried several solutions but there's no luck.
This is the component

```
export const MasterColourTable = ({
  totalMasterColours,
  masterColours,
  loading = false,
  onAddClick,
  onBottomInView,
}: MasterColourTableProps): ReactElement => {
  const { ref, inView } = useInView({ threshold: 0.03, triggerOnce: false });
  const { palette } = useTheme();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading && inView) onBottomInView();
  }, [loading, inView, onBottomInView]);

  const tableBackgroundColour = palette.secondary.main;

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '50%', height: 1, position: 'relative' }}>
      <TableContainer
        component={Paper}
        elevation={0}
        sx={{
          width: 1,
          maxHeight: 1,
          position: 'absolute',
          overflow: 'auto',
          msOverflowStyle: 'none',
          scrollbarWidth: 'none',
          ['&::-webkit-scrollbar']: {
            display: 'none',
          },
        }}
      >
        <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650, width: 1, height: 1 }} aria-label="simple table" stickyHeader>
          <TableHead
            sx={{
              opacity: 1,
              [`& .${tableCellClasses.root}`]: {
                backgroundColor: tableBackgroundColour,
                py: 0,
              },
            }}
          >
            <TableRow sx={{ height: ROW_HEIGHT }}>
              <TableCell align="left" sx={{ pl: 10, pr: 5 }}>
                <Typography variant="headings.h4">
                  Colour Code
                </Typography>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">
                <Typography variant="headings.h4">
                  Type
                </Typography>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">
                <Typography variant="headings.h4">
                  Hex colour
                </Typography>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ width: COLUMN_WIDTHS.swatch, px: 0 }} />
              <TableCell
                sx={{
                  backgroundColor: palette.background.default + ' !important',
                  borderLeft: `1px solid ${palette.divider}`,
                  borderRight: `1px solid ${palette.divider}`,
                }}
              />
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody sx={{ mb: FOOTER_HEIGHT }}>
            {masterColours.map((masterColour, index) => (
              <MasterColourTableRow
                ref={index === masterColours.length - 1 ? ref : null}
                key={`table-row-master-colour-${masterColour.masterColourNumber}`}
                masterColour={masterColour}
                onAddClick={(): void => void onAddClick(masterColour)}
              />
            ))}
            {loading && (
              <>
                <TableRowSkeletonMemo />
              </>
            )}
          </TableBody>
          <TableFooter
            sx={{
              height: FOOTER_HEIGHT,
              position: 'sticky',
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              zIndex: 2,
              [`& .${tableCellClasses.root}`]: {
                py: 0,
                border: 'none',
              },
            }}
          >
            <TableRow sx={{ bgcolor: tableBackgroundColour }}>
              <TableCell sx={{ pl: 10, pr: 5 }}>
                <Stack direction="row" spacing={1}>
                  <Typography variant="headings.h4" color="text.secondary">
                    Colours
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography variant="headings.h4">
                    Available:
                  </Typography>
                </Stack>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell />
              <TableCell />
              <TableCell align="center" sx={{ width: COLUMN_WIDTHS.swatch, px: 0 }}>
                <Typography variant="headings.h4">
                  {totalMasterColours}
                </Typography>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ bgcolor: palette.background.default, borderRight: `1px solid ${palette.secondary.main} !important` }} />
            </TableRow>
          </TableFooter>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

This is the picture of what I get when there are no results in the table.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**As you want to keep the total row at the bottom of the table even when there are no results. There is one way to achieve this is to conditionally render the total row only when there are masterColours. If there are no masterColours, you can render an empty placeholder row to maintain the layout.**

**Few things I have changed in your code:**

1. I added a condition to check if {masterColours.length} is greater than
   0 before mapping over masterColours to render rows. If there are no
   masterColours, it renders an empty placeholder row.
2. I also added a similar condition for rendering the total row in the
   footer. It will only render the total row if there are
   masterColours.

Here is the updated code (also added comment on it):

```
 export const MasterColourTable = ({
      totalMasterColours,
      masterColours,
      loading = false,
      onAddClick,
      onBottomInView,
    }: MasterColourTableProps): ReactElement => {
      const { ref, inView } = useInView({ threshold: 0.03, triggerOnce: false });
      const { palette } = useTheme();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading && inView) onBottomInView();
  }, [loading, inView, onBottomInView]);

  const tableBackgroundColour = palette.secondary.main;

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '50%', height: 1, position: 'relative' }}>
      <TableContainer
        component={Paper}
        elevation={0}
        sx={{
          width: 1,
          maxHeight: 1,
          position: 'absolute',
          overflow: 'auto',
          msOverflowStyle: 'none',
          scrollbarWidth: 'none',
          ['&::-webkit-scrollbar']: {
            display: 'none',
          },
        }}
      >
        <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650, width: 1, height: 1 }} aria-label="simple table" stickyHeader>
          <TableHead
            sx={{
              opacity: 1,
              [`& .${tableCellClasses.root}`]: {
                backgroundColor: tableBackgroundColour,
                py: 0,
              },
            }}
          >
            <TableRow sx={{ height: ROW_HEIGHT }}>
              <TableCell align="left" sx={{ pl: 10, pr: 5 }}>
                <Typography variant="headings.h4">
                  Colour Code
                </Typography>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">
                <Typography variant="headings.h4">
                  Type
                </Typography>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">
                <Typography variant="headings.h4">
                  Hex colour
                </Typography>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ width: COLUMN_WIDTHS.swatch, px: 0 }} />
              <TableCell
                sx={{
                  backgroundColor: palette.background.default + ' !important',
                  borderLeft: `1px solid ${palette.divider}`,
                  borderRight: `1px solid ${palette.divider}`,
                }}
              />
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody sx={{ mb: FOOTER_HEIGHT }}>
            {masterColours.length > 0 ? ( //Check if there are masterColours
              masterColours.map((masterColour, index) => (
                <MasterColourTableRow
                  ref={index === masterColours.length - 1 ? ref : null}
                  key={`table-row-master-colour-${masterColour.masterColourNumber}`}
                  masterColour={masterColour}
                  onAddClick={(): void => void onAddClick(masterColour)}
                />
              ))
            ) : (
              // Render an empty row as a placeholder if no masterColours
              <TableRow style={{ height: ROW_HEIGHT }}>
                <TableCell colSpan={5} />
              </TableRow>
            )}
            {loading && (
              <>
                <TableRowSkeletonMemo />
              </>
            )}
          </TableBody>
          <TableFooter
            sx={{
              height: FOOTER_HEIGHT,
              position: 'sticky',
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              zIndex: 2,
              [`& .${tableCellClasses.root}`]: {
                py: 0,
                border: 'none',
              },
            }}
          >
            {masterColours.length > 0 && ( // Check if there are masterColours
              <TableRow sx={{ bgcolor: tableBackgroundColour }}>
          <TableCell sx={{ pl: 10, pr: 5 }}>
            <Stack direction="row" spacing={1}>
              <Typography variant="headings.h4" color="text.secondary">
                Colours
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="headings.h4">
                Available:
              </Typography>
            </Stack>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell />
          <TableCell />
          <TableCell align="center" sx={{ width: COLUMN_WIDTHS.swatch, px: 0 }}>
            <Typography variant="headings.h4">
              {totalMasterColours}
            </Typography>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell sx={{ bgcolor: palette.background.default, borderRight: `1px solid ${palette.secondary.main} !important` }} />
        </TableRow>
      </TableFooter>
    </Table>
  </TableContainer>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Comment: React Developer, I want to render that tableFooter always, with results or without results. But instead of showing at the top I want to display at the bottom of the table. I appreciate your effort but not what I was asking